Reference for a proof of QMA-completeness of sparse Hamiltonian
It is well-known that the $k$-local Hamiltonian problem is QMA-complete for $k$ constants over $n$ qubits, $||{H}|| \in \text{poly}(n)$ under a reasonably large promise gap. See e.g. these notes.
Consider now the generalization of such a task: the sparse Hamiltonian. It extends the local Hamiltonian to row-sparse, row-efficient matrices. Such a task is certainly trivially QMA-hard, but is it QMA-complete? Can you provide a reference, or show perhaps the demonstration is obvious and follows from being able to efficiently simulate such matrices?

I might be missing but something given a certificate $|\psi\rangle$ and a sparse Hamiltonian $H$ that's promised to have an energy (eigenvalue) either $\le\alpha$ or $\ge\beta$ (with $\beta-\alpha$ not too small), what's wrong with:

Constructing a unitary $U=\exp(-iHt)$ using the machinery of Aharanov and Ta-Shma that you point to, and
Using controlled versions of this unitary, acting on $|\psi\rangle$, to run through phase estimation to determine its energy?

I think a difference between this and other proofs is that we swap out local Hamiltonian simulation with Aharanov and Ta-Shma's sparse simulation?
It might be the case that, by moving from local to sparse Hamiltonian simulation, we open the door for Merlin to trick Arthur with some garbage state $|\psi\rangle$ (say, if it's entangled with other states or something) and soundness fails, but I think that the standard proof of Kitaev probably carries through...

It's an interesting question.  In my mind it's somewhat analogous to asking if Circuit Satisfiability is in NP, given that we know 3-SAT is (while 3-SAT constrains the circuit much more than Circuit-SAT does).
That is, a surprising corollary of the Cook-Levin theorem is not so much that Circuit-SAT is in NP, but that even 3-SAT is NP-Hard.  Two surprising results of Hamiltonian simulation are that local Hamiltonian simulation and phase estimation is in BQP, and also that even sparse Hamiltonian simulation/phase estimation is in BQP.

Do you get sufficient accuracy in the energy estimation?

@Norbert isn’t that just requiring that $\beta-\alpha\in 1/\text{poly } n$, maybe with a worse polynomial compared to the local Hamiltonian case but still inverse-polynomial? Or am I missing something silly?

Sure, but do you get said accuracy with your 1. and 2.?

Or perhaps you’re commenting that for the local Hamiltonian case we require each local term to have bounded norm, but it might not make sense for the sparse Hamiltonian case?

Oh, maybe, I’m not sure.. Wocjan and Zhang controlled the errors for local Hamiltonian eigenvalue sampling to show that merely sampling from the support of the decomposition is promise BQP-complete. But they were silent (I think) about sparse Hamiltonians…

@Norbert Thank you! Assuming we can construct e^{-iH} perfectly, or that we use directly the block encoding for H (and estimate quantity different but related to the energy, c.f. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.1414), isn't quantum phase estimation returning an arbitrary epsilon-additive precision with O(1/\epsilon) queries to the oracle? Not sure why anything should change in the precision if we use a local or non-local Hamiltonian... do you have any further input?

@incud I guess it works, just didn't seem obvious. --- I think there is a much simpler construction: In the end it is sufficient for a QMA-verifier to accept with a probability equal to the normalized energy of a state; and this should be possible by simply picking a random (upper triangular) entry of H and accepting with a probability proportional to the energy of the given (symmetrized) Hamiltonian acting on a 2x2 subspace. I'll try to write up an answer discussing this in a bit more detail.

Thank you for the precious insight!
